# Linq Expression search filter giving error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: entity-framework, linq, expression

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SearchExpression<T>(string[] propertyNames, string[] propertyValue){
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    List<Expression> methodCalls = new List<Expression>();
    Expression finalExpression = Expression.Constant(true);

    foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
        var queryValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue[Array.IndexOf(propertyNames, propertyName)].ToLower(), typeof(string));
        var exp = Expression.NotEqual(propertyExp, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
        methodCalls.Add(exp);
        var toLowerMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, toLowerMethod);
        var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(toLowerMethodExp, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, queryValue);
        methodCalls.Add(containsMethodExp);
    }
    var orExp = methodCalls.Aggregate((left, right) => Expression.And(left, right));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExp, parameterExp);
}
```

When I try to debug it , its showing perfect expression but it is giving an error when in db column has `null` value.

Comment: @marc_s This isn't a simple `NullReferenceException` like the other question, and none of the answers there really help. This is a LINQ Expression specific issue relating to `And` vs `AndAlso`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Search<T>(string[] propertyNames, string[] propertyValue,bool isOr = false)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
            MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            var publicProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
              .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));


            Expression orExpressions = null;
            MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
            foreach (var callContainsMethod in from property in publicProperties
                                               let myProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name)
                                               let toLowerMethodExp = Expression.Call(myProperty, toLowerMethod)
                                               let myExpression = Expression.Call(toLowerMethodExp, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(propertyValue[Array.IndexOf(propertyNames, property.Name)].ToLower()))
                                               let myNullExp = Expression.Call(typeof(string), (typeof(string).GetMethod("IsNullOrEmpty")).Name, null, myProperty)
                                               let myNotExp = Expression.Not(myNullExp)
                                               select new { myExpression, myNotExp })
            {
                var andAlso = Expression.AndAlso(callContainsMethod.myNotExp, callContainsMethod.myExpression);
                if (orExpressions == null)
                {
                    orExpressions = andAlso;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!isOr)
                        orExpressions = Expression.And(orExpressions, andAlso);
                    else
                      orExpressions = Expression.Or(orExpressions, andAlso);
                }
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpressions, parameter);
        }
```

Comment: Err.. you took my answer, put it into your code, posted it as the answer and accepted it!?! Also you messed up and reintroduced bit-wise `And` and `Or` expressions which will not work. How about you accept my answer which will help other people who hit this issue and delete this one which adds nothing to anyone else but yourself?

Comment: @IanMercer i have implemented the code as i need to my work, your solution is for multiple property and single query i have modified as my need. I need it for multiple query and properties. Yes i agree that  i have got solution from your code. but i have modified., and i have checked it working fine.

Comment: It _cannot_ work for multiple properties, you are using bit-wise `And` and `Or` where you should be using `AndAlso` and `OrElse`. Also `Aggregate` is a cleaner way to aggregate the expressions into one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Expression.AndAlso` to combine the method calls.

`Expression.And` is a bitwise-and, `Expression.AndAlso` is the short-circuit evaluated logical and.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520(v=vs.110).aspx